# How to count not null values on pandas column then agregating

Tags: pandas, aggregate-functions, aggregation

I would like to count not null values of column per agregation level:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'agr' : [1,1,1],
                'col1' : [1, np.nan, np.nan],
               'col2' : [np.nan, 2, 3] })
df.agg({'col1' : [np.sum, np.count_nonzero],
       'col2' : [ np.sum, np.count_nonzero]})
```

This dummy aproach gives 3,3.
But I need 1,2. What is wrong here and how to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.count()` won't include NaN by default.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'agr' : [1,1,1],
            'col1' : [1, np.nan, np.nan],
           'col2' : [np.nan, 2, 3] })
df[['col1', 'col2']].count()
```

-

```
col1    1
col2    2
dtype: int64
```

Another way:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']].agg("count")
```

Comment: @Wen-Ben OP changed the question to not null only

Comment: That is funny ,sorry about that

Comment: how can we pass df,count to agr?

Comment: Sorry @Rocketq, what do you mean? Can you show us an example?

Comment: @Rocketq if you need just col1 and col2: `df[['col1', 'col2']].count()`

Comment: just in the example I gave

Comment: @Rocketq you mean this? `df[['col1', 'col2']].agg("count")`

Answer (score 0):

You need adding another condition `notnull`, since `0 != np.nan` is True

```
(df.ne(0)&df.notnull()).sum()
Out[305]: 
agr     3
col1    1
col2    2
dtype: int64
```

After your change

```
df.notnull().sum()
Out[322]: 
agr     3
col1    1
col2    2
dtype: int64
```